# IText 7 multiline field not auto breaking lines

Tags: c#, itext7

We recently switched from ITextSharp to IText 7, and it all seemed to work fine.
But then one of our customer send us back the pdf he got, and it didn't seem that the multiline field is auto breaking the lines, like it did on the ITextSharp.

Our fix right now is to split our string every 130 characters, and put in a `\n` on the closest space. For anyone having the same problem, here is the code we use:

```
 public static void SetFormatted(this PdfFormField field, string txt)
    {

        var rect = field.GetPdfObject().GetAsRectangle(new PdfName("Rect"));
        var fontSize = field.GetFontSize();
        var div = fontSize / 2.2;
        int length = (int)(rect.GetWidth() / div);
        field.SetValue(Format(txt, length));
    }

    private static string Format(string text, int length)
    {
        if (text.Length > length)
        {
            if (text.IndexOf(' ') == 0)
                text = text.Substring(1);
            string temp = text.Substring(0, length);
            int indexOfN = temp.IndexOf("\n");
            if (indexOfN > 0)
            {
                return temp.Substring(0, indexOfN) + Format(text.Substring(indexOfN), length);
            }
            int index = temp.LastIndexOf(' ');
            temp = temp.Substring(0, index) + "\n";
            return temp + Format(text.Substring(index), length);
        }
        return text;
    }
```

But this is more of a temporary fix, and not a solution.

(I know I said 130 characters, but it is what it split with in our field. It calculates what it should be. I don't gguarantee that it would work 100% for you)

We have tried to use `field.SetRichText(ourTxt)` but then it just didn't show, and the field is RTF enabled.

This is what it used to look like:[image: Used to be]
But this is what it looks like with IText 7: [image]

Comment: Do you have a sample file to reproduce the problem and code to call to reproduce it? Right now it seems like you have only attached a couple of helper methods

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same problem and it's driving me crazy. My fields would not wrap... until I set a background color:

```
    using iText.Forms;
    using iText.Forms.Fields;
    using iText.IO.Font.Constants;
    using iText.Kernel.Colors;
    using iText.Kernel.Font;
    using iText.Kernel.Geom;
    using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

    // Create a new PDF document
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("my_document.pdf"));

    // Create a page and add it to the document
    PdfPage page = pdf.AddNewPage();

    // Create an AcroForm and add it to the document
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);

    // Create a multiline text field that should wrap but does not.
    PdfTextFormField nonWrapping = PdfFormField.CreateText
        (pdf,
        new Rectangle(25, 727, 100, 100),
        "multiline-field-without-wrapping",
        String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Hello World ", 10)),
        PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA),
        9.0F);

    nonWrapping.SetMultiline(true);
    form.AddField(nonWrapping);


    // Create a multiline text field that DOES wrap but only because we set a background color.
    PdfTextFormField wrapping = PdfFormField.CreateText
        (pdf,
        new Rectangle(150, 727, 100, 100),
        "multiline-field-without-wrapping",
        String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Hello World ", 10)),
        PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA),
        9.0F);

    wrapping.SetMultiline(true);
    wrapping.SetBackgroundColor(new DeviceRgb(0.9F, 0.9F, 0.99F));
    form.AddField(wrapping);

    // Close the document
    pdf.Close();
```

I'm using .NET 7.0.0, iText7 7.2.4 and viewing the PDFs in Preview on Mac with Montery 12.6.1.

In both cases, the field sort of wraps when you click into it but only the field with the background color remains wrapped after the field loses focus.

Comment: I gave both fields the same name by mistake but the issue still exists even when you give them unique names.